# Is there a way to "implement" an interface within a different interface?

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface `IStat` which inherits `IEquatable` and `IComparable`

various stats will primarily be referred to as `IStat` as opposed to their actual type, and the implementation of `IEquatable` and `IComparable` will be identical regardless of the actual type.

IStat.cs

```
public interface IStat : IEquatable<IStat>, IComparable<IStat>{
    string GetKey();
    string GetValue();
    public new bool Equals(IStat stat) { // I'm aware I shouldn't use new
        return stat is not null && GetKey() == stat.GetKey();
    }
    public new int CompareTo(IStat stat) {
        return stat is null?1:GetKey.CompareTo(stat.GetKey());
    }
}

public interface IStat<TKey, TValue> : IStat {
    TKey Key{get;}
    TValue Value{get;}
}
```

ExampleStat.cs

```
// still requires implementation of Equals and CompareTo, and ExampleStat must be a struct
public struct ExampleStat : IStat<string, double> {
    private string m_Key;
    private double m_Value;
    public string Key=>m_Key;
    public double Value=>m_Value;
    public ExampleStat(string key, double value) {
        m_Key = key;
        m_Value = value;
    }
 }
```

is there a way to properly implement the `IEquatable` and `IComparable` methods inside of `IStat`? And if there isn't is there a way around this without having to write identical methods in every implementation?

EDIT

I added the implementations for Equals, CompareTo and the Constructor. I'm aware that using classes is the best way to handle my problem, but due to software constraints, for this I need to use a struct, which is where the issue of default behavior in my inheriting classes comes in.

Comment: First of all you simply cannot implement methods in interface.  Secondly I would create a base class StatBase that implements the main methods like Equest/Compare and leave then override IStat method whereever required.

Comment: latest c# allows method implemetation in an interface

Comment: @AliK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#concrete-methods-in-interfaces

Comment: @pm100 Appreciate the info will check it out did not know.

Comment: @AliK since the implementations are required to be structs, creating a base class does not work, interfaces are required.

Comment: @pm100 Unfortunately I cannot simply change the version of c# I am using, its for use in a software that doesn't at this time support the latest version of c# (I tried that route already and the compiled dll was incompatible).

Comment: Please do not use `new` to shadow the methods on the base interfaces. You can end up in a world of hurt when you cast to the different interfaces if they get implemented explicitly.

Comment: Please provide the full implementation. When you say "implementation excluded for brevity" you end up making it impossible for us to compile, making refactoring difficult, and answering becomes a guess.

Comment: @Enigmativity The actual implementation of the methods/constructor aren't relevant to the problem, but I've updated the code to show them nonetheless.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to implement a default `IComparer<T>`, `IEqualityComparer<T>` for any `IStat` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As @pm100 points out you can do this in C# >= 8.0, but in case you are using an older API and are forced to use a language version that does not have this feature yet, you need to use a base class, the `virtual` and `override` keywords and then implement the default method definitions in the base class as @AliK suggested.

```
List<IStat> stats = new();
stats.Add(new StatBase());
stats.Add(new StatDerived());
foreach(var stat in stats)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{stat.GetKey()}: {stat.CompareTo(stat)}");
}

public interface IStat : IComparable<IStat>
{
    public string GetKey();
}

public class StatBase : IStat
{
    public virtual string GetKey()
    { // default definition
        return "Base";
    }

    public virtual int CompareTo(IStat? stat)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class StatDerived : StatBase
{
    public override string GetKey()
    { // derived definition
        return "Derived";
    }

    public override int CompareTo(IStat? stat)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Base: 0
Derived: 1
```

If you really truly absolutely have to use a struct, you can make it a composition of your classes:

```
AStruct aStruct = new AStruct();
aStruct.PrintStuff();

public struct AStruct
{
    private List<IStat> stats = new();
    public AStruct()
    {
        stats.Add(new StatBase());
        stats.Add(new StatDerived());
    }
    public void PrintStuff()
    {
        foreach (var stat in stats)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{stat.GetKey()}: {stat.CompareTo(stat)}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I attempted to do this already and discovered that I required a value type, to be able to use this system as intended and since structs can't inherit from anything other than interfaces, this method didn't work (at least for my requirements)

Comment: @RWolfe sorry, I accidentally posted before finishing the answer. Please take a look at how I have implemented this now. If your issue is that you require this in a struct, you should change your question to show that that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `new` to shadow methods on the interface without creating the situation where you could have two implicit implementations of methods. You should almost always avoid `new` where possible.

The best alternative, when you can't use base classes, is to do this:

```
public interface IStat : IEquatable<IStat>, IComparable<IStat>
{
    public static class Default
    {
        public static bool Equals(IStat lhs, IStat rhs) => lhs is not null && lhs.GetKey() == rhs.GetKey();
        public static int CompareTo(IStat lhs, IStat rhs) => lhs is null ? 1 : lhs.GetKey().CompareTo(rhs.GetKey());
    }

    string GetKey();
    string GetValue();
}
```

Now your implementation can be written with a simple bit of repeated boiler-plate code.

```
public struct ExampleStat : IStat<string, double>
{
    private string m_Key;
    private double m_Value;
    public string Key => m_Key;
    public double Value => m_Value;

    public ExampleStat(string key, double value)
    {
        m_Key = key;
        m_Value = value;
    }

    string IStat.GetKey() => this.Key;
    string IStat.GetValue() => this.Value.ToString();

    public bool Equals(IStat other) => IStat.Default.Equals(this, other);
    public int CompareTo(IStat other) => IStat.Default.CompareTo(this, other);

}
```

This code is still in question, in my mind, as `new ExampleStat("Hello", 1.0).Equals(new ExampleStat("Hello", 2.0)) == true`. That shouldn't be true.

Comment: For my needs, Two Stats with the same key should be equal, regardless of value, I did however forget to add stat type into my equals method. I also do understand that typically that behavior is not useful.